# Jsp not found Package

Tags: java, jsp, web

Hi I have an error with a jsp, I have to access a bean present in a package called model but when I execute the code I am shown the error below, do any of you know how to solve it? I also added an image of the project structure, below I also added the java class of the model

[Structure of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5wCx.jpg)

**Error:** `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /processregistration.jsp (line: 2, column: 0) The value for the useBean class attribute Model.User is invalid.`

**Jsp Code:**

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*"%>
<jsp:useBean id="UserObj" class="Model.User"/>
<%
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    String passwordcheck = request.getParameter("passwordcheck");
    String nome = request.getParameter("name");
    String cognome = request.getParameter("surname");
    boolean check = false;
    //Verifico tutte le condizioni necessarie nel caso in cui una condizione non sia verificata torno alla pagina principale
    try {
        if ((password.equals(passwordcheck) == false) || (email == null) || (nome == null)
                || (cognome == null)) {
            check = false;
        }

        //Una volta effettuata la verifica dei parametri procedo alla registrazione
        else {
            //out.write("email: " + email + "\n password: " + password + "\n nome: " + nome + "\n cognome: "
                    //+ cognome);
            //out.write("Parametri coretti");
            check = true;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        check = false;

    }
    if (check == false) {
        request.getRequestDispatcher("/register.jsp").include(request, response);
    }
    //Controlli eseguiti con successo
    else {

        if(UserObj.Register(email,password, nome, cognome)==true){
            out.write("registrazione  riuscita");
        }
        else{
            out.write("registrazione non riuscita");
        }


    }
%>
```

**Model:**

```
package Model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import Controller.UserController;

public class User implements Serializable {

    private String Username, Password;

    public User(String Username, String Password) {
        this.Username = Username;
        this.Password = Password;
    }

    public Boolean Login() {
        return UserController.Login(Username, Password);
    }

    public Boolean Register(String Email, String Password, String Nome, String Cognome) {
        try {
            return UserController.Register(Email, Password, Nome, Cognome);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            return false;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: In the MVC paradigm, the JSP is for display.  Business logic and setting of data objects should be done in the servlets

Comment: Can you share your Model class also

Comment: Side note: your packages should have lower case names. `Model.User` looks _a lot_ like `User` is an inner class of a class called `Model` - so the package should at least be named `model`.

Comment: @Thomas show the image of structure of project, i have change with lower case but not change anything

Comment: @Hades i have share my model class

Comment: Well, that's why I mentioned it being a side note: it's meant to improve your code in general (by increasing readability) but is most likely not (directly) related to your problem or any solution.

Comment: "i have share my model class" - no you shared the `User` class in _package_ `Model` - Hades' question shows the point I was making in my side note: he got confused by the naming.

Comment: As for your problem: does the JSP compiler even see the other complied classes, i.e. are they put into `WEB-INF/classes` or into a jar in `WEB-INF/lib`? Or if this is the IDE's compiler already is it set up in a way that the IDE knows those classes will end up in one of those locations?